# Need help to deploy oracle database in godaddy server

Tags: android, database, oracle, web, web-deployment

Am Developing a website which is connected to an oracle 12c database(installed in  my local windows laptop). It uses the database to recover user data once  logged in. Am planning to deploy the website in godaddy. I have the following Questions before deploying.

1. If I deploy my database in go daddy, do i need to pay for oracle ?
2. If I have to pay oracle, Is there any other options which makes use of database free ?
3. Also planning to use the same database for Android App which i will develop after few days. Please suggest If i can able to make use of the database which is on godaddy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the Oracle 11g Express which is free (with some limitations on cores, database size and memory) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: @kevinsky I saw 11g Express edition is free to develop. Now my App is ready. How to migrate my database to godaddy.

Comment: @kevinsky Should i need to buy space from go-daddy and install it. Or it will be available already and i have to just migrate my data ? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to move some tables and they are small it might be easier to create the statements to create the tables and insert statements with sql developer which is also free from Oracle.

Or you can export your current data set using the datapump.  This will give you a file you can upload to godaddy.  Then you need permissions on the godaddy server to install Oracle.  Their FAQ can help you on this.